# Termux NumPy installation error (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, numpy, termux

I am trying to install numpy but termux gives errors

Error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy Failed to build numpy                    ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

If i am right, it required to install (pip install) additional libraries, but I forgot which ones...

I installed python 3.8.

I already tried it with python 2, python 3(3.11).

Comment: Which platform are you on? Numpy does have some numerical library dependency, the error message should quote which ones are missing

Comment: Phone. Android 12. Termux app.

Comment: You can install numpy for the latest python release with `pkg install python-numpy`. If you want numpy for python 3.8, you might have to build it yourself. Beware that the latest numpy version is only compatible with python 3.9-3.11 see the release on [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases)

Comment: @i0ui0u seen this https://superuser.com/questions/1724176/why-pip-throwing-an-error-when-installing-numpy-in-termux ?